# Boost http server example not working?

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio, server

I have copied the files (the ones from the "HTTP Server") from [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html), but it seems that it is not working. I have run the application with `0.0.0.0 5000 .`, but when I try to connect to the page localhost:5000 I get always 404 Not Found. What to do to make it run?

Comment: What if you bind to `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: Can you please describe the setup in more detail?  What are the expected results?  What file are you trying to serve?  Where is it located on the filesystem?  What is the exact URL are you requesting in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting an HTTP response with status code of 404, then the HTTP server is running, handling the request, and serving a response.  If the server was not running, then an HTTP response would not be returned.  The browser may provide additional details about the failure:

```
$ lsof -i tcp:5000 # verify nothing is listening to port 5000
$ curl http://localhost:5000/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
```

Verify that the path being requested in the HTTP request exists in the directory that corresponds to the `doc_root` parameter provided when starting the server.  Also, be aware that if the request path ends with `/`, then the server will append `index.html` to the path.  As seen in the [code](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.57.0/example/cpp11/http/server/request_handler.cpp#L45-L67), if the server fails to open the file specified by the path, then the server will respond with an HTTP response having a 404 status code.

```cpp
// Open the file to send back.
std::string full_path = doc_root_ + request_path;
std::ifstream is(full_path.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if (!is)
{
  rep = reply::stock_reply(reply::not_found);
  return;
}
```

Comment: It returns: `<html><head><title>Not Found</title></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html>`

Comment: @sop Understood.  If the server was not running, then there would be no HTTP response, as it would fail in a lower layer, such as the TCP transport layer.  Check that the `doc_root` contains the files being requested in the HTTP request.

Comment: Where is the doc_root?

Comment: `doc_root` is the third argument provided to the program at startup: [Usage: http_server <address> <port> <doc_root>](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.57.0/example/cpp11/http/server/main.cpp#L23)

Comment: what files are requested?

Comment: @sop Please update your question with answers to the questions in the comments.